# Cant get Gridview to refresh on update inside Update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i've tried every blog and forum answer I can find and yet still I'm stuck a few days on, wondering if anyone can help please.

My issue is I have a Gridview inside an UpdatePanel, linked to an SQLDataSource.

On page loading first time (not a postback) I pull information from three database tables and write this to a new semi temporary table in my database, then set the SQLDataSource to select all from this new tableand display in my gridview. This works great.

When the table is displayed the user can edit or select a row. If a row is selected it highlights it and writes to the temporary table that row is flagged as highlighted (for later re-rendering), this works ok.

If the user clicks edit I put the Gridview into edit mode with the following:

```
protected void DailySheetGV_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    // put Gridview into edit mode //
    rowEditted = e.NewEditIndex;
    DailySheetGV.EditIndex = rowEditted;
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM ReportTempTable";
    DailySheetGV.DataBind();
    // ## //
}
```

this works fine.

**My issue is** that when the user clicks Update, I write to my table the updated values, which works fine, but for the life of me I can't get it to refresh the Gridview by re-databinding with the values of the updated table (ie recreate the gridview from the tempTable).

I have so far tried using the autogenerated Update button, this runs through all the _RowUpdating(), _PreRender(), etc functions but no matter where I run my refresh code from it will not refresh my gridview or even stop showing the Update Button and chnage back to an edit button (note: If i hit the refresh button it does).

Here is my refresh code in its own function:

```
private void rebindGV()
{
    DailySheetGV.DataSourceID = null;
    DailySheetGV.EditIndex = -1;
    DailySheetGV.DataBind();

    UpdatePanel0.DataBind();

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM ReportTempTable";
    DailySheetGV.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
    DailySheetGV.EditIndex = -1;
    DailySheetGV.DataBind();
}
```

I have also tried using a link button Labeled 'Update' and setting its CommandName="Update" this actually updates and resets the gridview back to EditIndex=-1 (ie shows the edit button again) but debugging through my code doesn't run any _PreRender(), _RowUpdated, etc functions so doesn't update the Gridview data to the latest values as it doesn't actually re-render.

Any help is most appreciated as running out of hair to pull out.

Many Thanks.

Using MS SQL, ASP.NET4 and C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something about this forum that's magical as as soon as I posted this question I realised that 'what if I added this to here' feeling and voila! all working now :)

Anyway's to answer my question and to help others here is now my refreshGV code

```
{
    DailySheetGV.DataSourceID = null;
    DailySheetGV.EditIndex = -1;
    DailySheetGV.DataBind();

    UpdatePanel0.DataBind();
    UpdatePanel0.Update(); // new line added to get updatepanel to refresh

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM ReportTempTable";
    DailySheetGV.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
    DailySheetGV.EditIndex = -1;
    DailySheetGV.DataBind();
}
```

I will experiment a bit more when I have time to see which of these lines I really need.

Cheers

Comment: I am having the same issue except it is switched. The GV is updated but the writing to the SQL table doesn't work correctly. Would you please let me know how to edit it in my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861925/how-to-send-the-updated-value-of-a-checkbox-inside-an-updatepanel

Comment: Hi, hope you found your answer as your link no longer points to a valid question. All the best.

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to update it. I appreciate your response. Thank you. Your answer actually helped me, so +1

Answer (score 1):

Before you update the table back to temp-table / some table check weather the values are truly updated back to database or not. for any update queries in web applications please check the following tips.

- after you update check the content updated / not using break point.
- if the table in database is updated success fully then check the property of grid-view / list-view its auto-post-back set to true.
- if you are using update-panel, set event basis it is reloaded / not (just reload panel /refresh panel)
- sometimes the page itself not generates post-backs which may be the reason (it is not storing updated field vales / loading values...)

I hope you followed all the steps needed to debug app again...